# C program conditionals don't recognize actionable input

Tags: c, validation, io, console, conditional-statements

Although I can confirm that I am entering the right type of input into my C program, I can't get my conditionals to interpret it correctly.  When I run the following code, the program calls `lengthFormula()` successfully, then prints the `"Choose from the following..."` input prompt.

```
int main(void)
{
    char newCalculation;

    do
    {
        char newCalculation;

        lengthFormula();

        printf("\nChoose from the following:\n a.) Calculate the length of a multi-bar scene in this project\n b.) Calculate bar length for a NEW project\n c.) Exit\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);

        /* printf("%c", newCalculation); */

    }while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'b' );

    if( tolower(newCalculation) == 'a' )
    {
        float barLength;
        multiBar(barLength);
    }

    if( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'c' )
    {
        exitProgram();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter `a`, instead of calling `lengthFormula()` again, `main()` returns `0` and the program terminates.  When I uncomment the second printf() call and build/run again, entering `a` returns `a`, but then it still returns `0`/program termination instead of calling `lengthFormula()`.

At the suggestion of @simplicisveritatis, I've also tried placing my conditionals inside the main do-while loop like so, with the same results:

```
int main(void)
{
char newCalculation;

do
{
    char newCalculation;

    lengthFormula();

    printf("\nChoose from the following:\n a.) Calculate the length of a multi-bar scene in this project\n b.) Calculate bar length for a NEW project\n c.) Exit\n\n");
    scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);

    /* printf("%c", newCalculation); */
if( tolower(newCalculation) == 'a' )
    {
        float barLength;
        multiBar(barLength);
    }

    if( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'c' )
    {
        exitProgram();
    }

}while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'b' );



return 0;
}
```

How do I alter my conditions so that they recognize my input?  Please don't tell me to use `getchar()`, because every time I do, someone else tells me to use `scanf()`, which other people say is dangerous.  I just want to understand why my conditions don't work.

Comment: Why did they tell you to use `scanf()`?, any good reason please. Did you include `stdio.h` and `ctype.h`? And this `float barLength; multiBar(barLength);` is undefined behavior, because you never initialize `barLength`.

Comment: There are chapters to be written on how to get input from users, we know. People despise scanf, but others use it just the same. Some insist on cin >> v, others warn "that's going to give you a string"...yet, your scanf functions in context for the moment.

Comment: `cin >> v` has nothing to do with this question because this is [tag:c] not [tag:c++], and yes `scanf()` is horrible. Specially because it's not correctly thaught in books, they normally ignore it's returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring `newCalculation` inside the loop. The one used outisde the loop is not the same one you `scanf()`ed.

In fact, outside the `do` `while` loop, `newCalculation` is not even initialized, so when you pass it to `tolower()` it can have any value, it's not possible to know which one in principle.

Remove the declaration inside the loop,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char newCalculation;
    do
    {
        lengthFormula();

        printf("\nChoose from the following:\n a.) Calculate the length of a multi-bar scene in this project\n b.) Calculate bar length for a NEW project\n c.) Exit\n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &newCalculation);

        /* printf("%c", newCalculation); */

    } while( tolower( newCalculation ) == 'b' );

    if (tolower(newCalculation) == 'a')
    {
        float barLength = 0.0F /* please initialize this before calling the function */;
        /* Or just multiBar(0.0F) */
        multiBar(barLength);
    }

    if (tolower( newCalculation ) == 'c')
    {
        exitProgram();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I remove the declaration from inside the loop, then compile/build, I get the error

'newCalculation' undeclared (first use in this function)

It's already declared in the loop, where else can I declare it?!

I also tried declaring 'newCalculation'  globally, and while that compiles without a problem, it brings me back to my initial runtime problem.

Comment: No, the first declaration before `do { ...` is enough. You don't need anything else except, initilize it in case `scanf()` fails. Which is unlikely in this situation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with char newCalculation. In your sample, you declare it twice, once outside the do loop, once inside the do loop. What this means is you have two, and the one inside the do loop is not recognized by the while test, meaning that `tolower(newCalculation)` is not "seeing" the letter you enter, it's seeing whatever garbage is in the uninitialized newCalculation declared outside the loop. Remove the INTERIOR one.

Also, initialize it to zero where you declare it.

You show you have a habit for not initializing what you declare again with `float barLength;` Make that `float barLength(0);` or something like that.

That said, your test for 'a' did call for a bar length correctly. However, there was no chance the loop would repeat unless by shear accident the stack left a 'b' or 'B' in the outer newCalculation. What you really seem to intend, here, is to stop the program on a 'c'...which means you don't need a function exitProgram, just change the while test to something like:

```
while( tolower( newCalculation ) != 'c' );
```